# No usable encoder were found on the phone for resolution 176x144

Tags: android, rtsp, live-streaming, wowza

I am developing live video streaming application . I am getting this issue in micromax,lenovo etc .. Its working fine with other mobiles like samsung . So can you please suggest what might be the issue . Thanks for your valuable replays.

Comment: "No usable encoder were found on the phone for resolution 176x144".  is the issue in some mobiles where as in samsung kind of mobiles its giving positive result like "Supported resolutions: 1600x1200, 1280x720, 960x720, 720x480, 640x480, 480x320, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144"

Comment: and able to stream video perfectly with supported resolutions. Unable to stream video with mentioned issue

Comment: do you have that issue while calling startService() or calling canvas.drawBitmap() or showing a custom Popup menu?

Comment: I am not using canvas.Bitmap() . Actually in my application I am capturing the video by using camera and giving live video streaming to another android device and web browser by using wowza server RTSP(Real Time Transfer Protocol) protocal. So when I call initRtspClient(); this method I am getting issue.

Comment: But I can say onething that I am getting this issue with screen resolution HD Quality. So when the mobile doesn't support the HD Quality with defined screen resolution, it will not stream the video. So we have make it compatible to all types of resolutions.

Comment: Are you streaming the 176x144 video from the phone or to the phone? If you are streaming _form the phone_, how do you work around the fact that on many devices, the camera does not support such video resolution?